Getting Stale value of the context's state in next after update by context's another method
I have a next.js application where I am using context to manage the application. I am calling the context method to update the context's state. But even I get the stale value.
As you can see in the code, I called refreshVideoById method and after that, I called getVideoById which should return the updated value from the videos array, but I always get the stale value.
Real UseCase:- This page is basically to show the video details and poll the server to get the latest details of the video. Simultaneously update the video's context so no need to re-run the API call.
Even I checked in the react dev tools and VideoContextProvider has updated their state value.
VideoContext.tsx
type Videos = Video[] | null

type VideoContextType = {
  videos: Videos
  getVideoById: (videoId: string) => Promise<Video | null>
  refreshVideoById: (videoId: string) => void
}
const defaultContext: VideoContextType = {
  getVideoById: async () => {return null},
  refreshVideoById: async () => {},
}

export const VideoContext = createContext<VideoContextType>(defaultContext)

export const VideoContextProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [videos, setVideos] = useState<Videos>(null)

  async function getVideoById(videoId: string): Promise<Video | null> {
    try {
      const cachedVideo = videos?.find(v => v.id == videoId)
      return cachedVideo || await fetchVideoById(videoId)
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Failed to get video')
      return null
    }
  }
  
  async function refreshVideoById(videoId: string): Promise<void> {
    try {
      const originalVideo = videos?.find(v => v.id == videoId)
      if (!originalVideo || !videos) {
        return;
      }
      const updatedVideos = await Promise.all([...videos].map(async (video) => {
        if (video.id === videoId) {
          const updatedVideo = await fetchVideoById(videoId)
          return {
            ...video,
            progress: updatedVideo.progress
          }
        }
        else return video;
      }));
      await setVideos(updatedVideos);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(`Failed to refresh video with id ${videoId}`)
    }
  }

  const context: VideoContextType = {
    videos,
    getVideoById,
    refreshVideoById
  }
  return <VideoContext.Provider value={context}>{children}</VideoContext.Provider>
}

page.tsx
const VideoDetails: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
    const { getVideoById, refreshVideoById } = useVideoContext()

    /* Fetch video details */
  useEffect(() => {
    const videoId = window.location.pathname.split('/').pop()
    let intervalId: ReturnType<typeof setInterval>

    if (videoId) {
      getScript(videoId)
        .then((script) => setVideoScript(script.text))
        .catch((err) => console.error(err))
      ;(async () => {
        let video = await getVideoById(videoId)
        if (video) {
          setVideo(video)
          if (video.progress == 'video_created' || video.status == 'error' || video.status == 'timeout') {
            return
          }

          intervalId = setInterval(async () => {
            if (video) {
              await refreshVideoById(video.id)
              let updatedVideo = await getVideoById(videoId) // here I always get the old video object
              if (updatedVideo) {
                setVideo({ ...updatedVideo })
                if (updatedVideo.progress == 'video_created' || updatedVideo.status == 'error' || updatedVideo.status == 'timeout') {
                  clearInterval(intervalId)
                }
              }
            }
          }, REFRESH_VIDEOS_DELAY_MS)
        }
      })()
    }
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId)
  }, [])

  return (<VideoContainer />)
}

Why the following line(video object) is not getting its updated value after calling the refreshVideoById method?
let updatedVideo = await getVideoById(videoId)

